# Getting data from a POST request

Tags: python, django

POST data not always making to my logic, despite updating the django model properly

```
def new_record(request):
    form = RecordForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/new_record')
        else:
            form = RecordForm()

    item1 = request.POST.getlist('checkbox_1')
    item2 = request.POST.getlist('checkbox_2')
    item3 = request.POST.getlist('checkbox_3')

    print(item1)
    print(item2)
    print(item3)

    if 'on' in item1:
        print("Checkbox 1 is true")
        write_pdf_view(textobject='textobject', exam_record_number='123')
    else:
        print("Checkbox 1 is False")

    if 'on' in item2:
        print("Checkbox 2 is true")
    else:
        print("Checkbox 2 is False")

    if 'on' in item3:
        print("Checkbox 3 is true")
    else:
        print("Checkbox 3 is False")


    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/new_record.html',
                  context={"form": form}
                  )
```

What I'm hoping to do is basically check if a checkbox is selected and pass a value into a function if this is true, for now I've fixed y write_pdf_view values to something I know exists and that's not working either (I imported that above)

I feel like this might be trivial for someone with experience, I'm a new hobbyist just looking to learn! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error or issue you're encountering? It's not clear from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements are executing during GET and not POST.

I would recommend structuring your code using the class-based view structure, as follows:

```
from django.views import View

class NewRecord(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'main/new_record.html', {'form': RecordForm})

    def post(self, request):
        form = RecordForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        item1 = request.POST.get('checkbox_1', None)
        ##place the rest of your logic here

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/new_record')
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice. I learned a bit along the way. It appears now that my checkbox on or none are actually passing  to the logic for further process.